# Fetch with encrypted password

Tags: javascript, fetch, cryptojs

I'm trying to authenticate to an API via fetch. For that, I'm using an encrypted username and password. The problem is that no matter what I do, the response I get from the API is that my password is invalid. I know the password works because it was provided by my admins.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import CryptoJSAesJson from './helpers/helpers';

var username = 'myusername';
var pass = 'mypassword';
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(username).toString();
var password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(pass), 'mypassphrase', {format: CryptoJSAesJson}).toString();
var credentials = {
    user: hash,
    password: password
}

fetch("https://demo.mediainfo.com/api/user/login", {
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    method: "POST"
}).then(response => {
    // do something with the response
});
```

On helpers.js I have this code:

```
var CryptoJSAesJson = {
    stringify: function (cipherParams) {
        var j = {ct: cipherParams.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)};
    if (cipherParams.iv) j.iv = cipherParams.iv.toString();
    if (cipherParams.salt) j.s = cipherParams.salt.toString();
        return JSON.stringify(j).replace(/\s/g, '');
    },
    parse: function (jsonStr) {
        var j = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(j.ct)});
        if (j.iv) cipherParams.iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(j.iv);
        if (j.s) cipherParams.salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(j.s);
        return cipherParams;
    }
}

export default CryptoJSAesJson;
```

Unfortunately the API documentation is null so I'm not sure what could be the problem, the only message I get when fetching is: "Wrong password exchange. Please contact administrator."

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you encrypt credentials on client assuming you use HTTPS/TSL?

Comment: How are you intending to send the credentials? As application/json body? If so you aren’t actually currently assigning the stringified JSON to the body property of the fetch statement. Would need to at least be body: JSON.stringify(credentials)

Comment: Damn it, that was what I was doing, I forgot to copy that part :D

Comment: Yeah of course, this is just an example, I would be storing those on env variables on the real implementation

Comment: If this was your issue, please do not edit your code to fix the bug. People need to see where the bug was. Let people's answers and comments demonstrate on how to solve the issue instead.

Comment: No, that wasn't my issue. That was just me pasting it wrong here. Sorry.